# Is there a way to expose JVM C2 compiler statistics to JMX?

Tags: java, jmx

I'd like for instance to expose the number of methods that were compiled using C2 compiler in JMX, or number of de-compiled methods as well as the name of these methods ?

Actually I wish to have access to jstat compiler information but using JMX.
The information provided by JMX on compilation is quite sparse, only displaying total compilation time